# Zend Linked or Dependent DropDowns

Tags: zend-framework, drop-down-menu

Does anyone knows how to properly make dependent dropdowns using the Zend Framework?
I've found several ways to do so, but none of them is using the framework features.

Dependent Dropdown: The options shown on the "B" , depends on the option selected on the "A" .

Thanks for your help,
Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the processAjax() method in the action. What do you mean by using the framework features?

Comment: How would I do that? Do you have an example?

By using the FW features I mean using some built in functionality made for this, I've heard about making Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect and that sort of things..

Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 0):

This is currently no built in functionality for filtering selects in Zend Framework (v1.10).

The next best solution I came across was probably the Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect but I don't like it.

Iim planning to write my own FilteringSelect component by integrating the standard ZF component with ajax or jquery... one day!